# Spring security login and register

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

i want to with postman login to my web app which is secure. In the web browser normal i can write my login and password, but how to login by postman when i want to hit under endpoint for example /login ? I should create rest controller which will handle this situation or maybe is the way that automatically handle this situation? Is it a good idea to send username and password in url something like that /login?username=admin&password=admin or better in body?
Below it's my security config:

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
  }

  @Override
  protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return userDetailsService;
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleSocialUserDetailsService simpleSocialUserDetailsService() {
    return new SimpleSocialUserDetailsService(userRepository);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
          .headers().frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login*", "/success*").anonymous()
          .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/signup/**", "/css/*", "/webjars/**","/js/*","/image/*").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
          .successForwardUrl("/tasks")
        .and()
          .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll()
        .and()
          .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
  }
}
```

Comment: do you see the status 200 OK in postman when you attempt to login ?

Comment: i add in method configure httpBasic(), on begin when i do some get on endpoint i got 401, but when i will hit under this same endpoint but with basic authentication that will work

Comment: but I wonder what it will look like from the point of view if the frontend application written in react will want to authenticate on the backend side, under which endpoint I have to hit?

Answer (score 0):

What type of security are you using? You can configure Postman to send credentials in the Authorization tab (below example using Basic Auth):

[image]

Comment: I use default spring security, i didn't configure nothing more than is in my SecurityConfig above, i hit under the /login or / with Basic Auth as you propose but it's not working

Comment: I mean more that when I will write applications in react I would like to hit endpoint to log in to the application and be able to use it.